# How to use DQL for querying relationship table

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine-orm, dql

So far my DQL is working fine if i use man entity table. but i have one query where i need to access the relationship table like

Entities are `User` , `Tasks`

`UserTasks` is relation many to many

This is my SQL which is working fine

```
SELECT A.name , A.id from tasks
inner join usertasks B on B.task_id = A.id
inner join users C on C.id B.user_id
FROM tasks A
```

How can i convert that to DQL because i don't have any entity for Usertasks table

Comment: You don't have any entity for Usertasks table? You must create because of relationship.

Comment: Doctrine itself creates the relationship table in database, i didn't create it

Comment: You don't use the intermediary table, you just make a join on Users (or whatever is the alias of User relation in Task object).